# AWS autoscaling triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, scalability, autoscaling

I am going to move a very big wordpress website (in terms of DB) to AWS.
And I would like to understand the autoscaling triggers in order to find the best balance between costs and performance.

Are there best practices about how to configure autoscalling and what each one of them actually means?

Should I scale out based on CPU? NetworkOut? Disk I/O?
Is there something automatic which can decide whether the system under load?

Did not find nothing useful in AWS docs.

Comment: is it load balancing now? what is your current bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you need to choose CPU or RAM.

Anyway, you need to investigate your app behavior and find out what particular metric better describes load for your servers and what could be a bottleneck in your particular case.

If for example you have high "Network Out" while having low "CPU Utilization", your network coud become a bottleneck and you need to auto-scale based on "Network usage".